# How can I build a text editor in React with contentEditable boxes to wrap user input that allows dynamic insertion of new boxes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to build a text editor with React. I wish to wrap each paragraph the user enters with a "box" (which is a contentEditable HTMLElement) such that when the user press Enter, a new box will be inserted below the current working box.

During testing, I found out that it worked fine when trying to append a new box to the end of the page, but when I tried to insert a box in between two existing boxes, it did not work as expected.

Here is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/modular-text-editor-jm262i?file=/Components/Editor.tsx. Specifically, I am using the following functions to handle box insertion and text editing:

```js
  const updatePageHandler = (updatedBox: BoxItem) => {
    const updatedBoxIndex: number = [...Boxes].findIndex(box => box.id === updatedBox.id);
    const updatedBoxes: BoxItem[] = [...Boxes];
    updatedBoxes[updatedBoxIndex] = {
      ...updatedBoxes[updatedBoxIndex],
      html: updatedBox.html,
    };
    setBoxes([updatedBoxes, currBoxData]);
  };

  const addBoxHandler = (currBox: NewBoxData) => {
    const currBoxIndex: number = [...Boxes].findIndex(box => box.id === currBox.id);
    const updatedBoxes: BoxItem[] = [...Boxes];
    updatedBoxes.splice(currBoxIndex + 1, 0, { id: uuidv4(), html: "" });
    setBoxes([updatedBoxes, currBox]);
  };
```

And here is how each Box is implemented:

```js
export default function Box(props: BoxProps): JSX.Element {
  const [innerHtml, setInnerHtml] = useState<string>(props.html + "A Box for texts");
  const BoxRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    props.onUpdatePage({
      id: props.id,
      html: innerHtml,
    })
  }, [innerHtml]);

  return (
    <ContentEditable
      innerRef={BoxRef}
      html={innerHtml}
      tagName="p"
      onChange={event => setInnerHtml(event.target.value)}
      onKeyDown={event => {
        if (!event.shiftKey && event.key === "Enter") {
          event.preventDefault();
          props.onAddBox({ id: props.id, ref: BoxRef.current });
        }
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

I am following [this guide](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-build-a-text-editor-like-notion-c510aedfdfcc) and store an array of data for my boxes as a React state. However, according to what my debug code has logged, the useState did not seem to register the change in this array when `onAddBoxHandler` was called.

I am quite confused with why React did not register the state changes and would like to seek a fix to my issue.

Comment: Create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that you can replicate and do not post pictures in your question.